# How can I get the full execution time of a testcase?

Tags: html, selenium, coding-style

From start to the end of a testcase in Selenium IDE - HTML.

What command/target to do is useful?

Please give an example?

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you include sample code of what you've tried, what your results have been.

Comment: im very new to S-IDE. i found a few threads via google with the same question, but nobody has answers yet. i think with store or storeEval could realize this, but i am not sure.

Comment: i tried to store the server time from my page in a var and count it in the end of the test, but servertime is the server time not present.

Answer (score 0):

is a bit large, but it works  =P

```
[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getHours())} | hStart |
[info] script is: 2
[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getMinutes())} | mStart |
[info] script is: 8
[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getSeconds())} | sStart |
[info] script is: 0
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${hStart}*60*60 | hStartTos |
[info] script is: 2*60*60
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${mStart}*60 | mStartTos |
[info] script is: 8*60
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${hStartTos}+${mStartTos}+${sStart} | sStartTotal |
[info] script is: 7200+480+0
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${sStartTotal}/60 | sTomStartTotal |
[info] script is: 7680/60

[info] Executing: |pause | 300000 | Here your testcase |

[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getHours())} | hEnd |
[info] script is: 2
[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getMinutes())} | mEnd |
[info] script is: 13
[info] Executing: |storeEval | javascript{(new Date().getSeconds())} | sEnd |
[info] script is: 0
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${hEnd}*60*60 | hEndTos |
[info] script is: 2*60*60
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${mEnd}*60 | mEndTos |
[info] script is: 13*60
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${hEndTos}+${mEndTos}+${sEnd} | sEndTotal |
[info] script is: 7200+780+0
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${sEndTotal}/60 | sTomEndTotal |
[info] script is: 7980/60
[info] Executing: |storeEval | ${sTomEndTotal}-${sTomStartTotal} | ExeTime |
[info] script is: 133-128
[info] Executing: |echo | ${ExeTime} Minutes | |
[info] echo: 5 Minutes
```